# Can I use ntfs for /home

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

When trying to complete my Ubuntu 12.04.1 install I recently received the error message: "The file system type fat32 cannot be mounted on /home, because it is not a fully-functional Unix file system. Please choose a different file system, such as ext2."  Is it possible to select the ext4 file system for this /home mount, continue with the full Ubuntu install and then change the /home mount to the NTFS file system using the GParted application?  The intent of this partition is to enable file sharing between Windows 7 and Ubuntu.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are other tools to share files with Windows (I speak of Samba), but I am not experienced in this matter so I cannot leave an educated answer. I just thought I would share this small nugget that I have picked up.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/23190/ntfs-as-ubuntu-home-directory

Answer (score 1):

No, most of the system directories including `/home` must be on fully functioning unix filesystems, which neither fat32 nor ntfs are.

Comment: NTFS is POSIX-compatible, thus **can store [Unix permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/253474)**. There are many ways to achieve that like [using a user mapping file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Linux_compatible_permissions) in NTFS-3g or storing the permission in [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Windows_NT) in [`$EA_INFORMATION` stream](https://flatcap.org/linux-ntfs/ntfs/attributes/ea_information.html) (which is [what WSL does](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/))

Comment: and Unix permissions can also be stored on FAT32 by using [umsdos](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/UMSDOS) driver

Answer (score 1):

I think NTFS (using `ntfs-3g`) does not support Unix permissions. Recording permissions is necessary in the home directory; several programs require correct permissions to function. For instance, for security reasons, OpenSSH requires `~/.ssh` to have sufficiently restrictive permissions. If you try to store it on NTFS, it will lose the permissions, causing SSH to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `/home` on a NTFS partition in order to share data with my Windows applications. I am working ubuntu 12.04 lts and up to date don't have any problem.

I did this:

I have a NTFS partition for Windows Data on `/dev/sda6`, but you must use your NTFS partition. Attention, this partition must not contain Windows OS and you must have installed `ntfs-3g`.

I mount this partition to `/media` (but you can use `/mnt` too):

```
sudo mkdir /media/whome
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/whome
```

Now I copied the directory `/home` to the directory `/media/whome` using `cpio` instead of `cp`

```
cd /home
sudo find . -depth -print0 | cpio --null --sparse -pvd /media/whome/
```

Now I dismount the partition:

```
sudo umount /media/whome
```

Now to backup the old home folder:

```
 sudo mv /home /respaldo
```

Now mount the new partition `/home`:

```
sudo mkdir /home
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /home
```

Now the most important step. To mount this partition every boot do

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bk
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and add this line at the end:

```
/dev/sda6 /home ntfs nodev,nosuid 0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would would and have done is exactly the other way around...

- create `EXT3` or `EXT4 Linux` partition for `/home`
- install Linux `EXT` drivers on `Windows` aka http://www.ext2fsd.com/ (it's not perfect, but so isn't `NTFS` support in `Linux`)
- Permanently mount `EXT` partition in `Windows` an assign it letter (via GUI which comes with software)

*Linux have messed up my folders on NTFS partition few times (made them unaccessible), but I've never had this problem with* **EXT2FSD**

Keep in mind that EXT4 is open source, but NTFS driver was created by reverse-engineering. Which of course isn't bad, but I personally trust source code more.